# Issue with parsing using xml2js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml2js

I have an xml in which tag name contains colon(:)
It looks something like this:

```
<samlp:Response>
data
</samlp:Response>
```

I am using following code to parse this xml to json but can't use it because the tag name contains colon.

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
var fs = require('fs');

    fs.readFile(
  filePath,
  function(err,data){
    if(!err){
      parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        //Getting a linter warning/error at this point
        console.log(result.samlp:Response);
      });
    }else{
      callback('error while parsing assertion'+err);
    }
  }
);

};
```

Error:

```
events.js:161
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Response' of undefined
```

How can I parse this XML successfully without changing the contents of my xml?

[image]

Comment: Add `if (err)` inside the callback to see the actual error

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Please see the screenshot, parseString is not getting called since it's a syntaxe error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xml2js` allows you to explicity set XML namespace removal by adding the [`stripPrefix` to the `tagNameProcessors` array in your config options](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js#processing-attribute-tag-names-and-values).

```
const xml2js = require('xml2js')
const processors = xml2js.processors
const xmlParser = xml2js.Parser({
  tagNameProcessors: [processors.stripPrefix]
})
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    //handle error
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    xmlParser.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        // handle error    
        console.log(err) 
      } else {
        console.log(result)
      }
    })  
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the accepted answer but keep in mind that you can access a property using its key.

```
object['property']
```

so in your case

```
result['samlp:Response']
```